# Proof of onward travel by flight from another country

Tags: air-travel, uk, bookings, southeast-asia, proof-of-onward-travel

Let's say country X requires proof of onward travel to permit my entry. If I had a flight out of country X within the duration of my maximum stay, I have no problem. But what if I have booked a flight that originates in a different country, country Y, before the duration of my maximum stay is exceeded?

In order to catch that flight from country Y, I will have to have left country X on time. Does this flight from country Y count as proof of onward travel?

I am aware that there may be differences between countries and that it may depend on which country I am from. Further, it could depend on other factors such as the locations of countries X and Y.

In my case, I am from the UK and specifically considering Thailand, Indonesia, Malaysia, Singapore, Brunei, and the Phillipines. However, I am also more generally interested in whether there are any generalisations that can be made.

Comment: You would still have to show something for leaving X.

Comment: My viewpoint is to try to make things as simple for immigration officers as possible. In your scenario, you are asking them to make a somewhat syllogistic conclusion. It makes sense, however note that immigration is not always sensible. For example the requirement for onward travel we all know is essentially means nothing. Probably 99% of absconders had return tickets they never took. Same thing with detailed itineraries in Schengen countries, many times we fake them in order to apply at a particular embassy. They are almost meaningless however immigration wants the documentation

Comment: Looking at it logically, one purpose of an onward ticket requirement is to demonstrate your *intention* to leave Country X.  The ticket from Y does fulfill that purpose to some extent.  But another purpose is to demonstrate your *ability* to leave Country X.  Without this requirement, some visitors might enter X, spend all their money, and not be able to afford a ticket to get home, so they decide to stay illegally instead.  Showing a prepaid ticket out of X helps demonstrate that this won't happen to you - even if you blow all your money in X, you still have your ticket out.

Comment: But a ticket from Y doesn't help with this - if you blow all your money in X, you might not be able to afford to get to Y to catch your flight, and thus have no choice but to overstay illegally.  So only a ticket that actually departs from X would satisfy this requirement.

Comment: @NateEldredge That is a really useful way of looking at the situation and I find it very helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I have personally traveled a long time in Southeast Asia and never really had to show proof of onward travel, except in the Philippines. Otherwise, there's always the possibility to book a cheap flight, train or bus ticket.

Comment: I've had to show in Singapore more than once and maybe Malaysia one but I'm less sure about that.